# Intermittent javascript download issue

Tags: javascript, fuelcms

Have a strange intermittent issue that I spent ages trying to get to the bottom of a few months ago, but gave up. Want to give it another look.

I have built a site using FUELCms, and i'm very happy with it. It seems however, that sometimes not all the javascript requests are fulfilled properly. I get errors in the firebug console and have to refresh the page with a ctrl F5 to get the scripts to download properly. It only happens when I am logged into the CMS, and there a lot of javascript requests going on.

The errors I get in my console are unrelated and hard to replicate. Can be a different error each time.

The request completes with a 0200, but when I look at the file that brings about the jS error, it is corrupted. Strangely, sometimes with sections of other js appended to the end of the file, or in the middle of the file.

I spent some time with the admin from FUELcms, and I thought I had got to the bottom of it, but think I was wrong. No-one else using FUELcms seems to experience this.

It never happens on my xampp server on my laptop, only live.

Is this a problem with my host?

Baffled. Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated, I'm at my wit's end!

EDIT: Following Dan's suggestion below, here are some server details. Pretty much no nothing about the server aspect, so not sure what is relevant. So sorry if it's a bit of info-dump vfrom cPanel...

```
Apache version  2.2.17
PHP version     5.2.17
Architecture    x86_64
Operating system    linux
Kernel version  2.6.18-194.32.1.el5
```

FURTHER notes: When using FuelCMS inline editing, there are a lot of javascript http requests(total of 28 requests) made by the CMS. The largest of these is ckeditor, at 327Kb. The error mainly seems to occur with this file, and whilst watching the net console, this file always 'stutters' before the error.

Sorry if there's alot of superfulous info here, but am truly baffled. I'm hoping that someone else has experienced the same thing. It does seem to point towards my host not serving everything correctly though.

Comment: This definitely seems like it would be a server-related issue if you're not seeing the issues on your own system. I'd recommend adding some details regarding your server setup (and potentially HTTP compression, or other bits of hardware that may be hopping in the middle of an HTTP request). You may want to consider moving this question to serverfault as well.

Comment: I've voted to move the question over to ServerFault, but thank you for adding the additional details. Someone on the SF will probably know better where to look for this type of issue.

Comment: If your JS file contains sections from other JS files, that sounds like a concurrency issue when serving the file.  I don't see how that could happen in transit, or on your side.

Comment: Ok, cheers Dan. I don't know how to move a question over to serverfault - I guess just flagging it can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - think I've found the issue, but not sure how to solve it yet.

I've sat relaoding my page for past 10 minutes. The issue occurs whenever a js file takes longer than 5 seconds to download. Looking in the response headers I see:

Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=53

So I'm guessing here that for some reason the js files are taking longer than they should, and the connection is getting closed, and I'm getting a garbled js file with bits missing etc.

Don't know how to solve this though. Will investigate.

FURTHER:

It seems that this is an apache server configuration:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html

and since I'm on a shared server, I doubt my host will change it. I've been trying to look for ways to override, but I can't, and I imagine it would be terribly bad pratice to do so anyway!

If anyone knows anything more/different, then please let me know! For now I'm off to see what I can compress...

Thanks.